# How can you run the Plutus Playground and serve the Haddock documentation from the VSCode DevContainer?

Tags: plutus, plutus-playground, docker, vscode, dev-container

I am still looking to settle on a dev environment for Plutus contracts.
I am thinking about using VSCode with the devcontainer, but would like to know how well it all integrates. Is it easy to have the associated Playground and Haddock documentation alongside?

I am currently able to get cabal, Plutus server, Plutus Playground and Haddock docs in sync building Plutus in a nixos/nix container image. Would VSCode give me the same?

Answer (score 0):

To run the [Plutus Starter DevContainer](https://hub.docker.com/r/inputoutput/plutus-starter-devcontainer) from VSCode you have to:

1. Install [`docker`](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) and [`VSCode`](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)
2. Install [Dev Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) and [Remote Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) extensions for VSCode
3. Run `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash inputoutput/plutus-starter-devcontainer:latest -s`

You will initiate an instance of a Plutus Starter DevContainer, like this:

[image: docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash inputoutput/plutus-starter-devcontainer:latest -s]

4. Then, open `VSCode` and from the **Remote Explorer** and under **Dev Containers**, select `inputoutput/plutus-starter-devcontainer:latest` and then open a terminal (**Terminal** - **New Terminal**)
5. Then run `cd plutus-starter`
6. `cabal update`
7. `cabal build`

You have built the `plutus-starter` project from the Dev Container. You can code and build any `plutus` project inside it, including the `plutus-playground`.